# kivy 2.5d scene - graphics api with drawing/uix api

Tags: 3d, kivy, 2.5d

I know Kivy exposes its OpenGL context and some of its raw interfaces. If you *tamper* with OpenGL directly, or use lower-level modules like **kivy.graphics.trasformation**, what effect (in general) will this have on higher level widgets? Does everything cooperate seemlessly, or do the low level openGL functions have a habit of breaking layouts or making widgets buggy?

Are widgets fully 3D in implementation; although their interface is targeted for 2D?
Should I flatten my 3D simulation, using python, and just stay away from the low-level api's?

I am not good enough to build full 3D objects from meshes, yet it would be nice to have a few simple hardware accelerated transformations and texture manipulation/blending/projection.

---

- Could I extend most built-in widgets with this **Renderer** template? [GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/3Drendering/main.py)
- Will multiple instances of **Renderer** work side-by-side? (assuming the built-ins will work fine)

  - Nested? (Probably not, and limited if so)

---

I am hoping for answers with a list of caveats when mixing high and low level api, or, existing projects frameworks that were designed with 2.5D in mind (most of the projects I have seen commit pretty heavily to 3D object generation).

---

### Project Notes

I would like to set up a scene that is displayed as several layered 2D planes (using sprites/drawingAPI/Widgets), but is technically modelled after a 3D scene. The depth of the scene does not need full 3D support, but could benefit from 3D camera translation/rotation.

I would like to use high-level Kivy for Widgets and drawing API's. Right now drawing order and scaling should give my scene the depth I desire. But I am not sure how to get certain *zooming/panning* effects.

I am hoping to use the **garden.particlesystem** (designed as a flat 2D widget to my understanding). I plan to stack 3 instances, ultimately to create a fluid piping simulation.
I shouldn't need to do heavy 3D->2D projection first the first version, but eventually I can see it becoming a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does everything cooperate seemlessly, or do the low level openGL functions have a habit of breaking layouts or making widgets buggy?

Widgets don't actually know or care about what the graphics are doing - what will break them is if your own operations mean that the graphics are in a different place to the widget, so that the user is not clicking in the right place in widget terms.

You can in general avoid this by keeping track of your transformation matrix and applying it to the touch to see if it collides really. This is what the Scatter widget does, allowing arbitrary in-plane rotation and scaling without breaking the widgets it contains. The difficulty of doing this more generally depends on exactly what you're doing.

To directly answer your question, there's no inherent conflict between using low level instructions and widgets.

> Are widgets fully 3D in implementation; although their interface is targeted for 2D?

Kivy's main context doesn't have the gl depth test enabled, so there isn't any 3d clipping or anything, but it's still opengl and you can pass and manipulate 3d vertex coords if you want.

The example you post uses the generally useful technique of replacing a widget canvas (a list of instructions that's slotted into the parent context) with a RenderContext (which lets you locally enable the depth test, amongst other things such as setting shaders for this context).

> Could I extend most built-in widgets with this Renderer template?

In principle I guess so, but I think it would be more involved than you might think to get everything to actually work in a useful way, depending on what exactly you're doing. This includes the problem that if you start messing with the projection, translation or rotation of the context then you have to translate touches appropriately if you want widgets to keep working, which sounds annoying.

> Will multiple instances of Renderer work side-by-side?

Yes.

> Nested?

I think so, though you may have to be more careful about inheriting projection matrices etc from the parent.

> I am hoping for answers with a list of caveats when mixing high and low level api,

I don't really have anything to say other than the above, which is partly educated conjecture - nobody has done much work of this nature before.

You might be interested in nskrypnik's github repositories, which have some nice 3d examples (not exactly what you're trying, but the general principles of api usage are the same), or tshirtman's recently released ddd (3d) module in the [kivy garden](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.ddd) that again demonstrates the same things. I guess he was too modest to post this in his own reply!

Edit:

> The depth of the scene does not need full 3D support, but could benefit from 3D camera translation/rotation.

I'm not sure what you have in mind here, but when working with a few planes it might be relatively easy to live in true layered 2d and apply appropriate matrices individually to each plane. This might be okay to keep track of, and would let you easily transform touches appropriately so widgets work fine (just as Scatter does...you could even use that directly, if it's not too heavy).

Comment: My idea of of 2.5D is no mesh/vertex heavy drawing; instead euclidian vectors/geometry for drawing/control and sprites for raster effects. I want to spend my time modeling my simulation, not worrying about how it actually gets painted on screen (to a degree). Awesome references and feedback, and great suggestion for touch input transformation. My model is mostly driven by external data, so my UI requirements are mostly lightweight input handling.

Comment: I don't see anything from what you've said that should be too hard - the touch transformation stuff isn't that common, but it should work fine, and it's actually quite easy to do it generically (hence the existence of the Scatter). It sounds like it would be a good idea to try kivy and see how it goes - any problems should quickly become clear.

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in

Kivy - exploration of a future 3d inspector : http://youtu.be/2p-2jq5tXIw

code is shared in the description.

Comment: Will read up. I think he is just playing with the global GL context. Also notice that he "resets" the context when he switches tabs, that might be a sign that widgets don't operate in altered GLcontext (I imagine MouseEvents would need to be refined for proper interaction).

Comment: The code for the camera might be easy enough to do what I want. Doesn't fully provide a 2.5D solution, but that nearly answers my question.